# How to replace all php anonymous functions for fn() using regex on notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to update a legacy php code (7.0) for php 7.4 >=
and one of the new features that I would like to use the new `fn() =>` syntax, instead of `function() use () {}`

Unfortunately, I have hundreds of anonymous functions using CakePHP ORM like:

```
$query->matching('Tags', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Tags.name' => 'CakePHP']);
});
```

Using php 7.4 >= could be:

```
$query->matching('Tags', fn($q) =>
        $q->where(['Tags.name' => 'CakePHP'])
);
```

Sometimes using "use":

```
$query = $articles->find()->matching('Comments.Users', function ($q) use ($username) {
    return $q->where(['username' => $username]);
});
```

php 7.4 >= (use is not needed):

```
$query = $articles->find()->matching('Comments.Users', fn ($q) =>
        $q->where(['username' => $username])
    );
```

Or using two or more params:

```
$query->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
    return $exp->eq('published', true);
});
```

But when you have more than one instruction, fn () ***cannot be used***, for example:

```
$results->map(function ($row) {
        $row['age'] = $row['birth_date']->diff(new \DateTime)->y;
        return $row;
    });
```

I would like to use **notepad++ regex and replace in all files feature** to execute a regex and replace all "possible" `functions()` for `fn()`.

So, What REGEX could achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Find: function\s*\(([^\(\)]*)\)[^\{]*\{\s*return\s*([^;]*)\s*;\s*\}
Replace: fn\(\1\) => \2
```

Comment: Almost there: fn() does not uses "use (...)"

Comment: @celsowm updated. Check it again, please.

Comment: nice ! (I just dont know why the breakline are not preserved, would be cool, but no problem)